# throwing Uninitialized string offset error in php array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

```
$month = $this->input->post('get_month');
//echo $month; exit();
// get the employee salary [result_array()];
$insert_salary = $this->payscale_model->get_salary();
// print_r($insert_salary[0]['salary_amount']); exit();// correct value displayed 
//print_r($insert_salary); exit();  displayed the array correctly

for ($i=0; $i < count($insert_salary) ; $i++) { 
    $payscale[$i] = array(
        'employee_id' => $insert_salary[0]['employee_id'][$i],
        'payscale_amount' => $insert_salary[0]['salary_amount'][$i],
        'payscale_date' => $month,
        'payscale_total' => $insert_salary[0]['salary_amount'][$i],
    );
}
echo "value is:";
print_r($payscale); exit();
$insert_payscale = $this->payscale_model->set_payscale($payscale);
```

i'm getting the employee salary details from salary table and insert to payscale table with current month details. I successfully retrieved the salary details and now i want insert to payscale table using for loop and insert_batch using codeigniter. but php throwing the error Uninitialized string offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $month = $this->input->post('get_month');
    //echo $month; exit();
    // get the employee salary [result_array()];
    $insert_salary = $this->payscale_model->get_salary();
    // print_r($insert_salary[0]['salary_amount']); exit();// correcte value displayed 
    //print_r($insert_salary); exit();  displayed the array correctly

if(count($insert_salary)>0)  
foreach ($insert_salary as $ins) { 
        $payscale[] = array(
            'employee_id' => $ins[0]['employee_id'],
            'payscale_amount' => $ins[0]['salary_amount'],

            'payscale_total' => $ins[0]['salary_amount'],
        );
    }
```

or

```
if(count($insert_salary)>0)  
    foreach ($insert_salary as $ins) { 
            $payscale[] = array(
                'employee_id' => $ins['employee_id'],
                'payscale_amount' => $ins['salary_amount'],

                'payscale_total' => $ins['salary_amount'],
            );
        }
```

Comment: can we do this in forloop

Comment: using 2 for loop after getting the final result. so simply used foreach.

Comment: i dont get you, i'm doing insert_batch(codeigniter) here